# Why is the Rotavirus vaccine can be given only until the age of 8 months and 0 days?

Tags: vaccination

Any idea why there is such a strict age limit for this vaccine? [Reference](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/vpd/rotavirus/public/index.html)

Comment: Who says so...?

Comment: "This first dose of rotavirus vaccine should be given before a baby is 15 weeks of age. Vaccination should not be started for infants older than 15 weeks because there is not enough vaccine safety information for children who start vaccination older than 15 weeks. Also, infants should receive all doses of rotavirus vaccine before they turn 8 months of age." - quote from the Centers for Disease Control and Prevention. You can refer to the link I embedded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[World Health Organization: Age restrictions for rotavirus vaccination: evidence-based analysis of rotavirus mortality reduction versus risk of fatal intussusception by mortality stratum,2012, page 5](http://www.who.int/immunization/sage/meetings/2012/april/rvagerestriction_WHO_Mar28.pdf)

> WHO currently recommends that rotavirus vaccines should not be
>   initiated for infants aged 15 weeks or older, with all doses being
>   completed by 32 weeks.  **These age restrictions are driven by
>   concerns about intussusception risk.** Natural intussusception rarely
>   occurs before 3 months of age and the incidence increases 10-fold
>   between 3 and 6 months of age.

*Intussusception is a type of bowel blockage.